Did the ENIAC have any programming language?
On Wikipedia's entry for ENIAC, it states the ENIAC had 5 programming languages. I believe some of those are just names for different graphing systems, but ARC Assembly and Curry Notation System seem more promising of a more modern-looking programming language. Still, I looked up those names and I found nothing.

ENIAC coding system (1943-1946)
ENIAC Short Code (1946)
Von Neumann and Goldstine graphing system (Notation) (1946)
ARC Assembly (1947)
Curry notation system (1948)

So, did the ENIAC had any real programming language?

Define a “real” programming language.

@JonCuster, by "real", I mostly meant one that we know existed and that and we could call a programming language historically or maybe even modernly. I guess it looked like I was saying some programming languages are not actual programming languages. I really just could not find any of them on-line.

Do you mean "did it have a compiler, that compiled a file in text format into assembly code"? Or "were there advanced notation schemes that then were hand-converted into assembly"? As for notation schemes, maybe have a look at this blackboard picture.

Strange you name 5 languages used and still conclude there is none? Could it be that you got a very specific idea what you want it to be? If yes, it might help if you add what features  a "real programming language" needs to have to qualify - best start with what it's purpose would be. (Also keep in mind that the ENIAC today would hardy qualify as computer, thus any language being likewise alien to modern eyes)

"one that we know existed" Were any programming languages known outside the computer lab they were used at that time? Were even two of the few computers in exictense at that time possible to program withthe sam elanguage?

FWIW: The physical manifestation of an Eniac program was in the configuration of hundreds of patch cords and, in the settings of thousands of switches. I wasn't there, and I haven't read much that was written by the people who were there, but I imagine that they might not have thought of it as a "language" at that time. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ENIAC#/media/File:Glen_Beck_and_Betty_Snyder_program_the_ENIAC_in_building_328_at_the_Ballistic_Research_Laboratory.jpg

Re, "some programming languages are not actual programming languages." (See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_true_Scotsman .)

@SolomonSlow: From what I read (probably Wikipedia) later versions of the ENIAC could be configured entirely via numerically-addressed numeric-entry switches, which would be equivalent to machine code in ROM.

This question has a good potential answer which is a combination of @JonCuster and Raffzahn's comment: the languages used on early machines is alien to us AND I think we have 2024 centric expectations of what a "language" is which don't map to how programming was done in the 1940s, when "assembly language" (read: auto-coding) was still being envisioned/developed.

@supercat, Sure, but do you think that the people who programmed ENIAC 70 years ago (give or take) would have thought of that machine-code-in-ROM-equivalent as a machine language? Would they would have thought of the specification of higher-level steps of some computation that they wanted the machine to perform as "statements" in a source-code language? It sounds natural to me today, but by the time I learned anything about computers, people already were using languages like Lisp, and FORTRAN, and BASIC, and COBOL, etc.

@SolomonSlow: They would have viewed the machine's behavior as being described by a sequence of numbers.  I don't know when people would have started using the term "language" to refer to the way that numbers controlled behaviors, but the machine had thousands of switchbanks, each of which contained around a dozen ten-position switches, and aside from the base-ten orientation I would expect the relation between switch settings and behavior was probably not terribly different from something like a MIPS.

@SolomonSlow: I would expect that the ENIAC would have been programmed using programming sheets containing marked rows and columns of digits which may have used numbers instead of mnemonics to represent opcodes, but if e.g. operation #3 would add the contents of two registers, then a switchbank set to "3574219" might be equivalent to "ADD R57,R42,R19".

@supercat, Right, but OP asked whether the programmers used a real programming language.™ So, I thought it might be worth questioning, not only what we think is a real programming language today, but also, how would the builders of the machine have answered the question way back when?

@Schilive Can you just explain what makes the languages you list not being a language?

@Raffzahn, I did list them, but I could not find them, so I do not even know what they look like so I can't say whether they are "real" programming languages or not. Also, I did not think y'all would focus so much on "real". Sorry.

@Schilive Well, it is important, as Eniac is in no way a computer like we see today. It's a bunch of counters switches and alike, which get 'programmed' by ladies plugging wires between them according to lists made by engineers- those lists are the only written form of a program and as such more like wire diagrams than what you may expect.

@Raffzahn, those ladies did a whole lot more than just configure the machine "according to lists made by engineers." They were the programmers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ENIAC#Programmers

@Raffzahn: Per Wikipedia: "A number of improvements were made to ENIAC after 1947, including a primitive read-only stored programming mechanism using the function tables as program ROM,[67][68][69][70][71][72] after which programming was done by setting the switches[73]".

Plugboards may be more practical than switches if the number of relevant bits of information per instruction is highly variable.  If, for example, one wanted to have execution advance sequentially except when a "jump if positive", "jump if negative", "jump if zero", or "jump unconditonally" input is active and the result of the last operation satisfies that criterion, having to string a cable between an instruction-step output and one of those inputs, and another between an instruction-step output and a "jump target" input may be less convenient than setting rotary switches, but...

...one wouldn't need to include switches to set the target of any instruction that wasn't a branch.

@supercat, Removable plugboards were an important feature of some early computing systems. Programmers could wire up one set of plugboards to solve one problem while at the same time, the computer was running a different program from a different set of plugboards. Plugboards that were configured for some recurring problem could be saved for future re-use. I don't know a lot about ENIAC, but somewhere I got the impression that it lacked that feature. What I read seemed to say that the machine could be idle for a week or two at a time while the programmers were busy reconfiguring it.

@SolomonSlow: The thing I'm surprised wasn't done was replacing manual rotary switches with telephone-exchange steppers.  Technology to configure a set of steppers switches based upon a punched tape or stack of cards was well established by the 1940s, and could have allowed the machine to be reconfigured much more quickly.  My guess is that the time the machine was being configured wasn't really "idle" time, instead represented time during which maintenance could be performed.

"Linear Programming" was the problem ENIAC was used to solve, and "Programs" were the solution to those problems.  The "programming" of those 5 "programming" languages refers to the use of the computer, not the nature or character of the language.

TL;DR: There was none.
At least not in a modern sense where programming language means a (mostly) textual representation, intended to be translated by an automation (computer/program) into a representation that can be loaded and executed by a computer.
This is in part as the ENIAC wasn't able to automatically load a program before 1949 and even thereafter no capabilities for translation existed.

To get somewhere close to answering this it's important to keep in mind that ENIAC was in no way a computer in any of today's definitions. And at the same time the understanding of what programming means wasn't formed as today. It's like talking what a chicken and egg is before there was any modern chicken (*1).
Programming was, if at all, understood in a way like a radio or TV program: a fixed sequence of items. Not the flexible implementation of complex processes. Likewise was the idea of programming made using a form of textual/human readable write up describing a process that can be read like any other text, not a settled one. After all, anything written would have to be turned into a circuit anyway.
Heck, in 1945 even what we now know as Assembler and often consider the lowest form of programming possible wasn't invented. The whole idea of having a computer turning a human readable text into a program - aka an Autocoder (*2) - was absolute science fiction. Not to mention that no hardware existed to do so (*3).
Technically ENIAC was 'collection' of of components, most notably 20 'core' components made up from an ALU and a register. To 'program' it one needed to connect those units depending on the intended data flow and dial in (*4) the operations to be performed. Any 'language' was about to describe how to plug he wires, thus more like drawing schematics.

The above drawing by Von Neumann (using the notation he developed with Goldstine) might be the closest to an abstract programming language for the early ENIAC. (Taken from this very informative CHM-blog entry *5)
In later updates, after 1947,the function tables were modified and combined with a standard setup so they could be used more like a (read only) program storage. Programming was now reduced to setting some or all 1200 dials to what was needed. Some of the accumulators were now designated as registers for data, program counter and index registers.
It took another year until the setup was modified to read those settings from a punched-card reader, finally turning it into a stored-program computer. Only now could we even start to see ENIAC as a computer somewhat like today. Quite primitive, but at least comparable(*6).
All of this is still without anything what today would be identified as a programming language. Also without much storage - it wasn't until 1953 that ENIAC got a 100 word core memory based storage (~500 bytes).
As a result any 'language' during its usage would always have been strictly some private notation scheme used to prepare either stage (wiring, dials, punch cards), which then had to be manually turned into either of those formats. So if you want to see what either of those languages are, you may want to read the papers written about. Most notably R.F. Clipingerer's 1948 A Logical Coding System Applied to the ENIAC (HTML-Verion), giving a good overview.
Also interesting start might be this page with various stories around ENIAC programming. Of course one also might right away hire a modern 'expert' ;))

P.S.: Yes, I had to learn as well that the five item list in your question can be found all over the web, but virtually no page giving any further information. All this copy & paste kinda seriously sucks. It only satisfies superficial curiosity, but is useless for anyone looking for real knowledge.

*1 - Yes, they are descendants of dinosaurs which also laid eggs, nonetheless most chicken breeds we know and use today originate only about 800 years ago in northern Italy. So any question about chickens before then will get quite blurry.
*2 - Yes, Autocoder, as if the computer was programming itself. Essentially the first time developers dreamed of a computer that could be programmed by everyone without much computer knowledge ... shouldn't be hard to see the repetitions from Autocoder through COBOL, BASIC and 4GL all the way to today's promises of AI making programmers unnecessary.
*3 - In fact, the very first Autocoder/Assembler like programming environment was a hardware device, 'Planfertigungsteil' (a modern translation might be Program Manufacturing Device) as implemented in 1942-1945 by Zuse for the Z4 computer. This was an electro-mechanical hardware device which allowed to write a punched tape using abstract operation names as well as symbolic addresses. The device checked operations and their parameters during entry for being valid combinations.
Interesting here that Zuse who built the Planfertigungsteil (*3) envisioned the use of a higher programming language, Plankalkül, which would use a two-dimensional, almost graphical notation, quite unlike today.
*4 - A dozen real dials to be turned for each accumulator :)
*5 - Programming the ENIAC: An Example of Why Computer History is Hard goes to explains some of the issues with looking at real early technology when rooted in today's canon of terms and their meaning. A problem that questions of RC.SE users may quite easily run into. Luckily for this question, programming the ENIAC is among the examples used :)
*6 - An interesting effect was that this 'progress' as paid for by dramatic loss of performance. About 6 times slower than without and no more parallel operation of all units. But a huge improvement in programming speed. No longer hours or days of setting all wires and dials, followed by possibly many days or even weeks of debugging.

Thank you a lot for the research and writing it all -- I am always impressed by ENIAC's rich history. Out of curiosity, where did you get that image from?

@Schilive Oops. Source added.

I may be wrong, but it seems the book "ENIAC In Action" has a lot of information. In their website, they have a poster with, I think, some old programming language examples.

@Schilive got that book on my shelf.

Raffzahn, I just book the e-book!

It's unclear to me what "the above five item list" refers to. What are the five items?

@nanoman It's the list right at the center of the question asked.

@Raffzahn Thanks! I didn't even connect that because I assumed "the above" meant somewhere within this answer. Perhaps clearer if you said "your [OP's] five item list".

This answer supplements the excellent answer by @Raffzahn.
Having recently read Proving Ground – The Untold Story of the Six Women Who Programmed the World’s First Modern Computer, by Kathy Kleiman, Hurst Publishers, 2022. It’s about the women who first programmed ENIAC in 1945 and 1946, while it was still at the Moore School of Engineering at the University of Pennsylvania, prior to it being relocated to the US Army’s Ballistics Research  Laboratory (BRL) at the Aberdeen Proving Ground, Maryland.
All the women were mathematicians with university/college degrees in mathematics. During World War II, they were team leaders of human computers employed to use mechanical calculators and differential analysers to calculate ballistics tables for the US Army. They were then invited to work on ENIAC.
There was no programming languages for ENIAC, or an operating system or compilers. The women taught themselves how to program ENIAC by studying the circuit diagrams.
From page 137.

The six women had to find clues in the drawings Arthur left them.
… thinking about the diagrams of the front of the units, “we had to figure out  how you would put a problem on, how you get the machine to do what you wanted it to do. And you had to do that from the front by setting up switches and plugging in plugs and things of that sort”

they had to

string the units of ENIAC together to pass numbers from one unit to another for multiplication, division, and the other operations … numbers were called digits and these ten digit numbers passed between units through “digit wires” and along “digit trays”.
They needed to move the program pulse from the cycling unit-the GO! Of the ENIAC - to each unit to start its operation. The cycling unit pulse ran along the back of the units and could be used by Programmers start one unit or multiple units for the next step or steps of the program.
… programming of ENIAC meant “we had to hook the machine together … to give you sequencing”. It would be up to them to handle each and every logical and physical step of their program, and to prepare the entire “sequencing of a problem”.

Years later people working at BRL would call this type of programming as “programming by means of  pulses, switches, and cables” and others calling it “direct programming”.
By studying the drawings, one of the women realized one of the features of the master programming units was the ability to run loops. This was done by setting switches (page 139).
When setting up a program, the digit cable were thick and heavy, whereas the program pulse cables were thinner.
From page 147.
In developing a program, one of the women (Jean the mathematician) broke down complex trajectory equations (for ballistics) into something more manageable. Another women (Betty the logistician) broke those mathematical segments further into small and increment steps that ENIAC could handle.
To get ENIAC to add two numbers the steps required would have been:


Knowing accumulator 4 held the result of a prior calculation needed for the next step (the first number to be added, say 10).

Setting the operation switch of accumulator 4 to the Greek letter alpha to receive a number on the alpha digit input connector located above the programming switches

Setting the operation switch of accumulator 6 to A for transmit and add its number, say 5 to accumulator 4 via its A digit output connector.

Initiating accumulator 6 to transmit and accumulator 4 to receive on the same program pulse.

Keeping the result in accumulator 4 until it was needed later in the program



From page 149.
To simplify the programming process, the women devised “Pedaling Sheets”. These were large sheets of paper which had 27 columns and 16 rows.
The columns were labelled from the left, with column 1 being MP for master programmer, then  Acc 1 and Acc 2 for accumulators 1 and 2, Divider to the divider and square rooter, Acc 3 to Acc 10, HSM for high speed multiplier, and so for most of the units of ENIAC.
The rows represent each incremental step of a program. Each of the squares on the table would be filled with the program details, such as, digit wires, program pulse wires, switch settings and more.
To add more information, color was used via four colored pencils. It helped label the sequencing of pulses, switches and cables through the computer. It helped show the flow of data across the computer.
From page 155.
Eventually, the women discovered a way to parallel program ENIAC, because without it, ENIAC was too slow. It was difficult to do, because it relied on getting the timing right.

The concept was straightforward. A program pulse could be fed into more than one unit at a time. Thus, and accumulator could start addition and the high speed multiplier could start a multiplication at the same time.
But timing was a problem. The accumulator ran ten times faster than the multiplier – it could perform 5000 additions per second to the multipliers 500 multiplications per second. So if the next step of the program needed the results of the accumulator and multiplier the Programmer had to make sure that she waited long enough for the multiplier to finish it calculation before starting the next step with the accumulator and multiplier results.


Since you said "you looked up those names and found nothing", maybe it's illustrative to explain what those languages are, so you can see all of them are "real".
ENIAC coding system
I assume this refers to the way the ENIAC was originally intended to be programmed. A logical coding system applied to the ENIAC describes it like this:

During the first two years of operation, problems were coded for
the ENIAC by listing complicated sets of switch settings and cable con-
nections.

Programming was done on each unit:

The accumulator front panel contains, from bottom to top: program trays and sockets; the program
control neons; the input, output sockets; the program controls; digit input and output sockets; digit trays
and sockets; and finally the counter neons. [...] Program pulses
are routed from a program line to a program input socket 1i, 2i, etc. by a cable.

The referenced report has a diagram on page 9.
You can see how the switchboards and cables looked in a image from here and here
:

The ladies in the picture worked as ENIAC programmers, by the way.
ENIAC Short Code
One of the most important contributions by John von Neumann was what is now called the Von Neumann Architecture: Programs and data are the same, programs can be coded as numbers, and are stored in the same memory.
So choosing a fixed cabling for the ENIAC, and giving some of the accumulators dedicated roles, and by having an additional piece of hardware to decode pairs of decimal digits into control lines, one could just store a program in the "function table" (basically a table of coefficients).
That's very similar to how machine code works today.
Part of a table with short code from "A logical coding system":


Von Neumann and Goldstine graphing system (Notation)
This is described in the report Planning and coding of problems for an electronic computing instrument.
It's the equivalent of the high-level language you were looking for.
Keep in mind that typical applications for the ENIAC were for example to numerically solve differential equations. Nobody can look at a differential equation and then start plugging in cables into the different ENIAC units. So the algorithm to solve this differential equation had to be written down, in an abstract way first, and this was then translated by hand into cabling and coefficients, or a list of orders.
Diagrams are still used in computing today, and without the need to have a text file translated by the computer into something else through a compiler, it's actually a more obvious way of notation than today's high-level languages.
Here is an example from the report:

Note that a program loop is literally a loop in this diagram.
You may also be interested in Plankalkül, a similar high-level language developed by Konrad Zuse for the Zuse computers.
ARC Assembly
The ARC (Automatic Relay Calculator or Automatic Relay Computer) was actually a different computer than the ENIAC, but I assume what is meant here is to apply the same principle eo the ENIAC that Kathleen Booth developed for the ARC.
Her idea was instead to use a short "graphical" description for the "orders" or instructions instead of using the numbers itself. I have seen this way of notation for the successors of the ENIAC, but not actually for the ENIAC itself (though maybe it was). An instruction was typically written with arrows indicating the flow of values.
This is similar to assembly today, but without the mnemonics.
Examples for the ARC can be found in the report Coding for the ARC (this uses "to" instead of arrows, because that was simpler to do on a typewriter).

Curry notation system
Haskell B. Curry was a logician. Together with Schönfinkel he developed a logic of "combinators", which has applications to the lambda calculus (and, very indirectly, modern functional programming languages based on the lambda calculus, like the Haskell and ML family).
A set of slides on how exposure to the ENIAC connected with his work can be found here.
Very briefly, his notation is about composabilty of computational elements (much like the logical combinators). It's again a very graphical notation, though at least the logical combinators all have formula and reduction rule equivalents.

Not only are diagrams still used, graphs of various forms are the predominant ways ot represent code within compilers for analysis, with the linear textual representation only being used for input and output though a stream device.

In the first picture, it looks like there's a syntax error in cable 53. :)

Formally, as someone said, a computer language is necessarily translated into a machine readable language. I once programmed BASIC that was directly executed by the hardware. By this definition, it would not be a language.
But the question really is about whether a text string represents instructions that a computer can execute. Von Neumann provided an excellent example of a language.
I cleaned up this picture:

WE (appear to) SEE:

initalize B and S registers to 0
store constant to the X register
increment B register by 1
test positive and jump (the square boxes)
increment register M and store in the X register
negate register S
loop with index ranging from 1 to register B

This crude, ad hoc language lacks syntax, but the control structures are there.
Amazingly, This stuff looks nearly identical to some of the old code I've had to fix the countless bugs in.

Re. the first paragraph: if a computer language is something that can be translated into something directly executed by machine, and your BASIC was a directly executed by machine, then surely even by that strict definition it counts as a computer language (using the trivial identity translation)!

@gidds I don't know, but it was a special research board manufactured by the electrical engineering Department of the university. I saw it in a display case in the hall because they were proud of it. In any case, the identity function is trivial.
